# Как подключить библиотеку, чтобы на другом ПК её было достаточно поместить в папку с exe файлом?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2012

Для работы программы необходим `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll`. На некоторых ПК он может отсутствовать, поэтому решил, что следует поместить его в папку с программой.

Подключаю его через ссылки (reference) и на моём ПК всё работает. Однако, расположение библиотеки указывается полностью и на другом ПК придётся поместить его в ту же папку.

Собственно, как подключать библиотеку, чтобы при выполнении она бралась из папки, где находится exe файл?

Разбираться с тем, как организовать установку на пользовательском ПК нет времени (да и нужды).

Comment: Оказалось, что всё подключается нормально. Проблема в том, что я запускал программу из сетевой папки с другого ПК.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Указать в свойствах референса `CopyLocal = True`. Но обратите внимание на замечание @pavelip -- чтобы работала интеграция с Вордом, прежде всего на компьютере д.б. установлен Ворд.

Answer (score 5):

Сборка `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll` - это всего лишь обертка вокруг COM объектов MS Word. Для правильной работы на другом ПК должен быть установлен MS Word.

Answer (score 3):

Полный путь в reference - это информация для студии и компилятора. В самом exe библиотека будет подключена по имени - `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`.

При запуске среда будет искать ее в стандартных местах, в том числе и в папке приложения.

При выставленном на референсе CopyLocal = True (по умолчанию) студия скопирует dll в папку с exe, так что вам достаточно будет просто скопировать на пользовательский ПК всю папку целиком.

Answer (score 2):

dll по-умолчанию сначала ищется в папке с exe и только если её там нет в папке windows, а если и там нет то начинает поиск по папкам из глобальной переменной PATH

Comment: А ещё в каталогах, указанных в манифесте. А ещё в GAC. А ещё в текущем каталоге.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx